# JAR files for AKKA (2.4 preferably) on android (java version 1.6 compiled - NOT 1.8)

Tags: java, c#, android, akka, akka.net

I have been looking for a very long time now for the jar files for AKKA (preferably 2.4) compiled for Java 1.6 or 1.7 and NOT 1.8!

If the internet had corners, I'm sure I would have seen all of them by now! BTW, I'm programming in Java, not Scala.

I'm using AKKA often in my projects, but I really would like to use it for a multi-platform project I'm working on and it should run on Android as well. Not as a client but as a local application. I have tested it on a Raspberry Pi with Linux - a comparable combo to Android - and that showed fantastic performance/multi-threading on such a small device.

But Linux supports Java 8, whereas Android doesn't. So I need the AKKA JAR's compiled for use in Java 7 or 6.

I have read all the answers on pretty much every forum out there about the topic, but a link to a location where to find these was nowhere to find.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is like I was afraid for. I know it is still early, only 2 days after asking the question, but IMO, it usually means that chances are great no good answer will follow (or maybe in a couple of weeks or months).

I think this mysterious AKKA version is rather a myth and I could not wait for it any longer anyway. Besides the question if this version exists, the possible security problems arising from such an 'older version' in production code have also always been in the back of my mind.

Therefore I have been experimenting with AKKA.NET and C# in Visual Studio 2017 (with Xamarin) the last couple of days (since I asked the question, actually).

Too my own surprise (previous experiments with C# and platforms other than Windows did go bad every time), the stress testing is currently running fine on Windows, Android and iOS !

Dozens of actors are creating dozens of child actors (also creating child actors) and throwing around diverse messages and replying ! I used a little memory management to avoid 'Out of memory' and so far Windows is running this code fine for over 24 hours and Android and iOS are running this continuously for over 6 hours without any problems !

I'm running the latest version of AKKA.NET in the project (not an 'old' version thus, like it would be the case in Java) and it is currently running on both Android 4.4 (KitKat) and 7.1 (Nougat). The Android 4.4 is an older smartphone with primitive specs and even on that little machine all is spinning lovely and smooth as I had hoped for, You have to love AKKA ...

This looks promising and it seems like the project will be done entirely in C# and I never thought I would say that ! Porting the existing code is going well so far, I keep my fingers crossed !

Anyway, if somebody knows the location of these mysterious Java AKKA JARs, I'm still interested and as that was the original question asked, I do not know if I should leave this question open or not. I appreciate your input and reflections on this.